# Using Scheduled Callout response to trigger another callout

Tags: apex, trigger, future, schedule

I'm having trouble with my current callout/trigger setup.

My current architecture is like this:

Scheduled job - runs every 5 minutes:

```
global class Scheduled implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        CalloutClass.CalloutMethod();
    }
}
```

CalloutClass:

```
public class CalloutClass{
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void CalloutMethod() {
        //Make Callout
        //Get response
        //Update object
    } 
}
```

Trigger Class - This is called from the actual trigger and is triggered by `CalloutClass.CalloutMethod()`:

```
public class ObjectTriggerHelper {
    public static void TriggerHelper() {
        AnotherCalloutClass.CalloutMethod();
    }
}
```

AnotherCalloutClass:

```
public class AnotherCalloutClass {
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void CalloutMethod() {
        //Make another callout
        //Update object
        //chain ends here
    }
}
```

My problem is that the scheduled job requires my `CalloutClass.CalloutMethod()` to be future since it's coming from a scheduled job. But this gives me an error because `AnotherCalloutClass.CalloutMethod()` is also future, and you can't invoke a future method from a future method. But I can't make `AnotherCalloutClass.CalloutMethod()` not future, since it's also being called from a trigger.

What would be the best way to take care of this? Put all the callout code in `AnotherCalloutClass` into the object trigger? Or will I have to do something with Queueable jobs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you cannot call future method from another future method.

But you can call a future method from a queuable method and a queuable from another queuable.

I would advise making both `CalloutClass` and `AnotherCalloutClass` as queuable

```
public class CalloutClass implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts{    

    public static void execute() {
        //Make Callout
        //Get response
        //Update object
    } 
}


public class AnotherCalloutClass implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts{    

    public static void execute() {
        //Make another callout
        //Update object
        //chain ends here
    }
}


public class ObjectTriggerHelper {
    public static void TriggerHelper() {
        System.enqueueJob(new AnotherCalloutClass());
    }
}

global class Scheduled implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
       System.enqueueJob(new CalloutClass());
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it would help! Thank you! How would I pass arguments  from `ObjectTriggerHelper.TriggerHelper()` into the `AnotherCalloutClass()`?

Comment: Create a parameterised constructor in queueable class accept values as class level variables and then use them in execute?

Comment: Ah I see. I was curious if the `QueueableContext` object could be used to be make it a bit cleaner, but a constructor would work fine too. Thank you!